# Laravel image intervention unable to init from given url

Tags: laravel, model-view-controller, controller

Good evening, i hosted a Laravel project and found some bug.
First of all, here is my code in my controller:

```
$request->file('FotoHT')->storeAs('FotoHT', $filenameToStore); //this is to safe

$path = asset('storage/app/FotoHT/'. $filenameToStore);
  
$width = Image::make($path)->width();
$height = Image::make($path)->height();
```

I save a picture, and it works but when i try using

```
Image::make($path)->width();
```

it give me the wrong url. It give me

```
https://myweb/public/storage/app/FotoHT/_MG_9549_1578913993.jpg
```

while the image should be accessed from

```
 https://myweb/storage/app/FotoHT/_MG_9549_1578913993.jpg
```

Can anyone give me a help/solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to save the image encode to the public path

```
$fieldFile = $request->file('FotoHT');
$image = Image::make($fieldFile)->width(); 
Storage::disk('public')->put("FotoHT/".$filenameToStore, (string) $image->encode());
```

Comment: the answer you give will give me the same error.
'Unable to init from given url'
because the path will give the wrong url there is 'public'

Comment: This should work, of not you need to check your public disk definition

Comment: so when i first save the image i use this code?
>'Storage::disk('public')->put("FotoHT/".$filenameToStore, (string) $image->encode());'

Comment: I updated the answer, as I said basically you take the image from the request and pass  it with the width then store is

Answer (score 0):

```
$path=$request->file('FotoHT')->storeAs('FotoHT',$filenameToStore);
$width = Image::make($path)->width();
$height = Image::make($path)->height();
```

Try this command.You can use asset() helper method for img tag in view